# Converting C++ project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a C++ project developed with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, that now I want to convert to Visual Studio 2010.

I've opened the VS2008 solution with VS2010 and to run the default conversion. The conversion went alright, but then my project was "unloadable": Visual Studio shows it in the menu, but below it says "The project was unloaded", and there's no way to open it.

[image: A screeshot of my VS2010 conversion attempt]

What could I do?
Why do the project result "unloaded"?
Why does it refuse to open it?

Many thanx to all

[Edit] If I click on "reload project", here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: didnt your VS2010 ask for converting the solution to new version?

Comment: And when it offers do save up a back up copy or else u might be F*cked

Comment: Try to use 'Reload Project' in the converted solution. What error do you get? You might have installed some add-on to your VS2008, that is not installed on your VS2010.

Comment: @Rohit Yes, it asked and converted. I've saved a backup copy.

Comment: @Morten Frederiksen it says "the project cannot be opened because its project type (.vproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

Comment: Very strange. I have done a lot of upgrading. Never seen this. The .vcproj project file should be converted to a .vcxproj file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the unloadable project from the solution. Then add an existing project and select the VS2010 vcxproj file that was created by the project conversion. If it doesn't exist try to add the original VS2008 vcproj file , which should be automatically converted in the process.